# List of type Pet, Pet has child classes Dog, Cat, etc. How do I tell which child class it is?

Tags: c#, list, console, parent-child

so I have a "petstore" console program that stores a list of type Pet, Pet can have child classes of type Dog, Cat, Rabbit, etc. So if I have a method that prints out animal information, how would I say which type of animal they are?

Below is the method that prints out animal information

```
public void ShowPets()
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have these animals: ");
    foreach (Pet p in pets)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(p.Breed + " who is a " + p.Age + " year old " + p.GetType());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

this is the output when that method is called.

```
terrier who is a 12 year old PetStore.Dog

persian who is a 2 year old PetStore.Cat
```

so I would like it to say just 12 year old Dog or Cat or Llama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `p.GetType()`, try `p.GetType().Name`.

Comment: Boom, exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!